# The view users.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

I'm making a to-do list web with my friend. So, I have created the register function with email authentication, and it works fin. I pushed it to the GitHub and my friend pulled it and tried it in his laptop.

But when he clicks "register" he got this error `The view users.views.view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

We literally have the same code since he pulled the code from my repository, we both user virtual environment, installing from the same requirements.txt, and we both uses WSL2.

This is the code 
`views.py`

```
class UserRegister(CreateView):
    form_class = UserRegisterForm
    template_name = 'users/form_register.html'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks')

    # Forbid logged in user to enter register page
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('tasks')
        return super(UserRegister, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    # Send email verification
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()

            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate your account'
            message = render_to_string('users/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('login')
        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
```

`form_register.html`

```
-- Register -->
        <section>
        <div class="register-card">
        <h2>Register for an account</h2>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="txt_field">
                <input type="text" name="username" required placeholder="Username">
                <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email">
                <input type="password" name="password1" required placeholder="Password">
                <input type="password" name="password2" required placeholder="Confirm password">
            </div>
        <div class="register-button"><input type="submit" value="Register"></div>
```

Comment: There’s nothing returned from the `else` branch…!?

Comment: What should I put in the `else`?

Comment: What do you *want* to put in the `else`? What *should* be returned if the form was filled in incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm.. let me google a bit more about this issue. Thanks a lot though for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to always return some `HttpResponse`. If form is not valid, then you have nothing in return. Method `self.form_invalid` is returning such response with errors, so you should use it.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        ...
        return redirect('login')
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: So I put that into my code and it gives me this error `'UserRegister' object has no attribute 'object' django`. So, I put `self.object = self.get_object()` into the code and it gives me this error now `UserRegister is missing a QuerySet. Define UserRegister.model, UserRegister.queryset, or override UserRegister.get_queryset().`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView - read this. You need to set `model = User` in `CreateView`.

Comment: Okk, I've done that, but now it gives me this error `Generic detail view UserRegister must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.` T.T

Comment: This looks like a problem with another thing. I will not help you step by step with everything :) Basically, you should probably not create object by yourself in `CreateView` (I refer to `user.save()`).

Answer (score 0):

While carrying out tests within my project, I faced a familiar challenge.

ValueError: The view loginForms.views.UserLoginView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

I figured out that the return render() statement should be properly aligned within the if request.method == 'POST' block to ensure it is only executed after the form is processed and found to be valid.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = forms.UserLoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("Form is valid")
        print("Username:", form.cleaned_data['userName'])
        print("Password:", form.cleaned_data['password'])
        
return render(request, 'loginFormsDemo/userLogin.html', {'form': form})
```